# How to get latest version string from a collection of folder where folder name is version string

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script, cmd.exe

for folder structure like below

```
RootFolder
   |
   |--1.2.3 
   |--1.2.4
   |--2.1.3
      ...
      ...
      ...
```

Under RootFolder, there are a collection of folders, and they all named with version string

by using Windows Batch command, is there a way to sort them and get the largest version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Get the "last" version from a directory of directories

An interesting question, since it's Windows batch! [`dir`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121.aspx) is your friend here; borrowing from [PabloG's answer over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97782):

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /O:G-N') DO ECHO %%I & EXIT /B
```

Place in `RootFolder` named `lastversion.bat` (or whatever). You can test by invoking from `cmd.exe`<sup>1</sup>.

Please note that I have only tested this using a very **very** limited number of *"version-like"* directory-named directories.

### Explanation

`FOR /F %%I IN` - Loop (`FOR`) through the following file set (`/F`), using the variable `I` (`%%I`)<sup>2</sup>

`'DIR *.* /B /O:G-N'` - List all files (`*.*`) in directory, in bare format (`/B`), sorting (`/O:`) reverse-alphabetically<sup>3</sup> (`-N`) directory-first (`G`)<sup>4</sup>

`DO ECHO %%I & EXIT /B` - Print the **first** filename and immediately terminate (`EXIT`) the **batch file only** (`/B`)

### Additional Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> `@ECHO OFF` [suppresses command echoing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462.aspx), but you probably knew that already

<sup>2</sup> `%%I` - use two percent signs inside a batch file, or if from an interactive prompt, just `%I`

<sup>3</sup> **reverse alphabetically** means we aren't caring about which version was actually written to last and just grabbing the highest version number; this might not be desirable

<sup>4</sup> group directories first so that plain files will get sorted to the end and thus ignored

Comment: thanks but it get the latest folder by date instead of compare the actual content. will be risky if greater version folder is not created later than folder that has smaller version

Comment: @jojo This version should return the **highest version number, regardless of date**. If I'm wrong in what you're asking, and you do want to get the latest version *by modification date* you could try `-D` instead of `-N` in the `DIR` specification. (I think you maybe read my link instead of the answer!)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, i haven`t tried and as you said i read the link instead of your content. after tread thru your detail explanation. i think it should work.

Comment: No worries- let me know if it doesn't and I will troubleshoot @ amend :)

Comment: 1.0.0.2 will be small than 1.0.0.12

Comment: @jojo Ah yes, that's a thorny one. It's the subject of an [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242913/windows-dir-command-order-by-name-and-something); and an [obligatory coding horror blog post](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/). tl;dr version: 'natural' sorting is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

"Natural" numeric sorts that recognize and sort numbers by there numerical value are a royal pain with Windows batch. It can be done, but the fact you have multiple numbers makes the problem that much more cumbersome.

The problem is easily solved with [JSORT.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) - a pure script based utility (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

To simply get a sorted list:

```
dir /b /ad RootFolder | jsort /n
```

To list the highest version number only:

```
dir /b /ad RootFolder | jsort /n /r /c 1
```

To set a variable to the highest version:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad RootFolder ^| jsort /n /r /c 1') do set "largest=%%F"
```